# How to get Activity's content view?

Tags: android

What method should I call to know if an Activity has its contentView (once the method **setContentView()** has been called)?

Answer (score 545, accepted):

```
this.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

or

```
this.findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

or

```
this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView()
```

Comment: or `getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.content)` :)

Comment: this works fine as far as fetching the Parent view is concerned...
BUt..if i try
this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundDrawable(d);
it dosent work..
Can you please suggest..
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you install a layout from XML using `setContentView(R.layout.my_view)`, this returns the *parent* of that layout.

Comment: Hello @ernest I have a sort question like If in my layout i have one image on top than two tab in tab bar. and in bottom a SatelliteMenu, Want to do blur on menu items are opened.

Comment: Sorry if I am wrong but @Jay Lieske explanation should be totally added to the answer (I leave the edit to him as he made the point)

Comment: Be careful. Calling [getDecorView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#getDecorView%28%29) before `setContentView` might prematurely “lock in various window characteristics”. So might calling `findViewById` ([bug 199710](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199710)).

Comment: would you help me out to get view of fragment , after updateLocale( )
or onResume in Activity,

Comment: content doesn't exist for Android.Resource.Id.

Comment: for kotlin use property call like `window.decorView.rootView` :)

Answer (score 23):

You can get the view Back if you put an ID to your Layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_relative_layout_id"
```

And call it from findViewById ...

Comment: This is the most robust way to get the root of an installed layout.

Comment: What do you pass to `findViewById` ?

Comment: @trans View contentView = findViewById(R.id.my_relative_layout_id);

Answer (score 13):

How about

```
View view = Activity.getCurrentFocus();
```

Comment: How does this not have more thumbs up? Works great!

Comment: @aeskreis because in my case it returns null `currentFocus?.let { ... } `

Answer (score 11):

You may want to try `View.getRootView()`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also override `onContentChanged()` which is among others fired when `setContentView()` has been called.

Comment: ernest's answer will give you the current focussed view even if contains scrollable view

Answer (score 3):

### **If you are using `Kotlin`**

```
    this.findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content)
                         .rootView
                         .setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no "isContentViewSet" method. You may put some dummy requestWindowFeature call into try/catch block before setContentView like this:

```
try {
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTEXT_MENU);
  setContentView(...)
} catch (AndroidRuntimeException e) {
  // do smth or nothing
}
```

If content view was already set, requestWindowFeature will throw an exception.

Answer (score -3):

The best option I found and the less intrusive, is to set a tag param in your xml, like

**PHONE XML LAYOUT**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:tag="phone"/>
```

**TABLET XML LAYOUT**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:tag="tablet">

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

and then call this in your activity class:

```
View viewPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), String.valueOf(viewPager.getTag()));
```

Hope it works for u.

Comment: How does this answer the question?