# Getting the layout when calling onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-activity

Can i possibly get the layout of my activity when back key was pressed?
or something that could identify the contentView of that Activity?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Why would you need the View, when the UI is no longer shown

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273436/how-to-get-activitys-content-view Use this in your `onBackPressed()` method.

Comment: its because, i dont use intents, i only setcontentview everytime i have done something.

Answer (score 2):

```
((ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0)
```

This should return you the Root View of current activity

Answer (score 0):

Add id to your parent view of layout and then get the reference by using findViewById() providing the id of the parent view.