# NullPointerException when trying to take screenshot programmatically

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, screenshot

I need to take a screenshot which I was coding in my game result screen.

I used the following method that I found in StackOverflow:

```
public void TakeScreenShot(){
    Date now = new Date();
    android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

    try {
        String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/PICTURES/Screenshots/" + now + ".jpg";

        v1 = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        File imageFile = new File(mPath);

        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
        int quality = 100;
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Screenshot OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but I'm getting `NullPointerException` at `Bitmap.CreateBitmap`.

My Bitmap and Views are global and I try to call method in `OnCreate`.

> 11-04 15:20:17.868 13569-13569/com.finger W/System.err:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

How can I solve this problem?

> I FOUND SOLUTION!

**I try to call takeScreenshot method in onCreate and always i got same result all different variation, but i try call method in "Share Button" click event, now its working. Thank you.**

Comment: `v1` or `v1.getDrawingCache()` will be `null`. Check before use. Or you are mistaken in the actual code line.

Comment: Hello @greenapps, i check if statment and my v1.getDrwaingCache is return null everytime, but i got same result Unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem once. try using this

```
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);


// Without it the view will have a dimension of 0,0 and the bitmap will  be null          
v.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight()); 

v.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I get NullPointerException in line 96, and my line 96: v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

Comment: try these options : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8817003/1515467

Comment: Hello @Manas,

I tried all of these options but everytime i got same result, CreateBitMap NullPointer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
  private void takeScreenshot() {
        Date now = new Date();
        android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

        try {
            // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
            String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

            // create bitmap screen capture
            View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
            v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            File imageFile = new File(mPath);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            int quality = 100;
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            openScreenshot(imageFile);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And this is how you can open the recently generated image:

```
private void openScreenshot(File imageFile) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

If you want to use this on fragment view then use:

```
View v1 = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

instead of

```
View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

Comment: It is the same code...

Comment: I got same result.

Comment: did you replace this line View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();

Comment: I changed my method completely with your code,

Comment: what's new error then

Comment: Same result, CreateBitMap NullPointerException

Comment: Hello @siddhesh, i found the solution. i try to call takeScreenshot method in onCreate and always i got same result, but i try call method in "Share Button" click event, now its working. Thank you.

Comment: Glad you solved it ...