# Pass the same View to a function that you are using in the setContentView()

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, view

I have the following function: `createEl(View view, ....)`

I have to go to the same View function I'm using in the:

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.

I tried with:

```
View view = (View) getLayoutInflater().Inflate (R.layout.activity_main, null);
```

But it does not work.
How can I do?

Comment: Exactly what happen? Your layout not showing after using that ?

Comment: @Piyush: Nothing happens, element is not inserted.

Comment: do you add the view to the layout after you inflate it? can you post more of your code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you are using different instances of the layout. Inflate the view and use that in `setContentView()`.

Try this

```
View view =  getLayoutInflater().inflate (R.layout.activity_main, null);
setContentView(view);
```

Now you can use `view` the way you want. It would be the same instance which is loaded in the activity.

Comment: There are other methods to get the loaded view but this should suit you best. see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273436/how-to-get-activitys-content-view